# How to show private posts on your profile, but not in the general feed in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In each of your posts aka "wins" you can make it public or private. If it's private, it will only be displayed in your profile and not on the general feed. I have displayed my profile controller, the form used to submit a post aka a win, the schema, and the profile show view.

Profile Controller

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
def show
     # grab the username from the URL as :id
if (User.find_by_username(params[:id]))
  @username = params[:id]
else 
  # redirect to 404 (root for now)
  redirect_to root_path, :notice=> "User not found!" 
end

@wins = Win.all.where("user_id = ?", User.find_by_username(params[:id]).id)

end
end
```

Schema

```
create_table "wins", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "description"
t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
t.string   "image_file_name"
t.string   "image_content_type"
t.integer  "image_file_size"
t.datetime "image_updated_at"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.boolean  "display"
end

add_index "wins", ["user_id"], name: "index_wins_on_user_id"

end
```

Show Profile

```
<%= render 'pages/home' unless user_signed_in? %>

<div id="wins" class="transitions-enabled">
<% @wins.each do |win| %>
<div class="box panel panel-default">
  <%= link_to image_tag(win.image.url(:medium)), win %>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p><%= win.description %></p>
    <p><strong><%= win.user.name if win.user %></strong></p>
    <p class="date"><%= win.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></p>

    <% if current_user && (win.user == current_user) %>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= link_to edit_win_path(win) do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to win, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Submit Your Post aka Win

```
<%= form_for @win, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
<% if @win.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
 <h2><%= pluralize(@win.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this win from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @win.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :image %>
<%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control" %>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :description %>
 <%= f.text_field :description, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :display %>
<%= f.select(:display, options_for_select([['Public', 1], ['Private', 2]]), {}, { class: 
  "form-control"}) %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<%= f.submit class: "btn btn-danger" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why don't you have a column in the db, called public? Set it to false as default and then update to true if the post wins? Just a thought

Comment: If you set up relationships between your models correctly then your fetch there for `Win` should be as easy as `@user.wins` without having to manually compose conditions. It's not clear why you load a user, then throw it away.

Comment: @tadman, thanks! But I in the user profile I want to show public and private wins, while in the general feed I only want to show public wins. How would I do that?

Comment: A proper ActiveRecord structure would allow things like `@user.wins.where(context: 'public')` if you have columns of that sort which can be queried easily.